# How to enable sound connection between sipster / pjsip in docker and outside world?

Tags: docker, sip, voip, pjsip

With sipster/pjsip sucessfully installed I would like to follow through the [basic sipster example](https://github.com/mscdex/sipster) and record the sound from a sip connection to that sip server. Now if I run this on a local arch linux machine the sound gets recorded fully, but if I do the same on a docker machine, that I start with

```
docker run -p 5060:5060/udp -it myContainer
```

the SIP connection works, but there is no sound recorded.

A friend told me that SIP uses RTP for sound transport and that this protocol binds UDP ports from 16384 to 32767.

Now if I do

```
docker run -p 5060:5060/udp -p 16384-32767:16384-32767/udp -it myContainer
```

this takes ages and crashes eventually.

Is there a way to narrow down the RTP port range in sipster or pjsip? And am I even on the right track or might the issue be connected to the docker not having a sound device?

Comment: Docker might not be happy with trying to forward nearly a quarter of all available ports. Does it still crash if you use a smaller range? Are you sure that range is correct?

Comment: @ChrisTanner This is the range from the RTP standard, cf. https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/10718041/rtp-port-range. I don't know which segment of this pjsip uses and how to restrict it. Of course docker (or my Mac host) is unhappy with such a broad range. With a range of hundred ports it works well. So I'm searching for an option to narrow down the range.

Answer (score 2):

Docker is not able to map a lot of ports at once. In my case I created a rtpproxy image and then I create several docker containers instances mapping 1000-by-1000 ports per container.

I am talking to a lot of guys about it and everybody says I am crazy and why I need 10k ports mapped .. then I have to explain how VoIP works ...

Regards

Luis

Comment: Thanks. This looks like a solution for deployment into production. As far as I understand SIP needs one port for initiating the communication (usually 5060) and then for each parallel RTP voice connection it binds a UDP port from the range of 16384-3276. How do you go about development, where you know you will only need one parallel connection?

Comment: In development you can set a low RTP range in rtp.conf. You can use 10000-10100 and then use -p 10000-10100:10000-10100/udp to use it on docker

Comment: @ Luis: Nice solution for Asterisk. But my idea was to run pjsip standalone as a library for node / sipster. But neither in the pjsip directory nor in the sipster docu I'm able to find a relevant config. Maybe it's a selection that has to be set by the pjsip-consuming software and sipster didn't implement it yet.

Comment: @IwanLD I am now working with PJSIP in Jedi mode yet to help you :-( sorry

Comment: How did you map the ports using rtpproxy? @LuisMachadoReis

Comment: @albertovielma you cab use -p -p 5060:5060/udp -p 10000-20000:10000-20000/udp - [more info](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose)

Comment: @IwanLD we resolved using the manual port mapping for now but we have to focus on this issue again. Waiting some people get free to focus on this one.

Comment: @IwanLD you are right this is a confirmation for production environment. To development we use a docker-compose stack to help and we do the hard tests on an staging environment closing every single component to guarantee the tests are good to roll out to production

Comment: Hey folks! Sorry by the 8 year late to answer, I was just not logged in. Now I forced my browser keep logged in to avoid miss something,