# How to receive SIP audio and send wav stream to Google Speech recognition API in node?

Tags: node.js, audio, speech-recognition, asterisk, sip

So far I've been trying [sipster](https://github.com/mscdex/sipster/), but it has some forbidding limitations ([e.g. lack of configurability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39995778/how-to-enable-sound-connection-between-sipster-pjsip-in-docker-and-outside-wor/)). Any ideas how to do this? Maybe with an node wrapper for asterisk like [asterisk-manager](https://github.com/pipobscure/NodeJS-AsteriskManager)?

In some more detail the basic idea is

- have a virtual sip client running, that can receive a SIP connection
- get the audio from that connection into regular wav form
- stream that wav audio to the Google speech API
- have additional ways to act on the sip stream via node, like play back a sound

Comment: `sipster` *is* configurable, you can pass pjsua2 config options to `init()`. The options can be found in the pjsua2 documentation, they are not listed in the `sipster` documentation because there are quite a few and it would be duplicating documentation.

Comment: Assume your "wave stream' means "streaming continuous" in google docs , you will need to go route of GRPC / proto-buffers on the googl side. you should look over your api for access to the audio buffer's bytes... Assuming those to be in encoded fmt && bitrate compatible with speech api input, you can just ArrayCopy.myAudioBytes() && do the write to the goog.api.channel you had opened for speech ... https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/grpc/src/main/java/com/examples/cloud/speech/StreamingRecognizeClient.java#L169

Answer (score 2):

This post is quite old, and it looks like things have improved a lot on the Google side, both on the speech processor itself, which is getting more and more accurate, and on the Node.js side, as the [Node.js client](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-speech) that interfaces with Google Cloud Speech API is getting updated on a regular basis.

As per @arheops advice, one might want to take a look at Asterisk's EAGI and Node.js in order to get audio samples transcribed by Google.

The following EAGI bash script might help in that regard (detailed instructions available [here](https://github.com/phsultan/asterisk-eagi-google-speech-recognition)) :

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read all variables sent by Asterisk store them as an array, but won't use them
declare -a array
while read -e ARG && [ "$ARG" ] ; do
        array=(` echo $ARG | sed -e 's/://'`)
        export ${array[0]}=${array[1]}
done

# First argument is language
case "$1" in
"fr-FR" | "en-GB" | "es-ES" | "it-IT" )
  LANG=$1
  ;;
*)
  LANG=en-US
  ;;
esac

NODECMD=$(which node)

# Second argument is a timeout, in seconds. The duration to wait for voice input form the caller.
DURATION=$2
SAMPLE_RATE=8000
SAMPLE_SIZE_BYTES=2
let "SAMPLE_SIZE_BITS = SAMPLE_SIZE_BYTES * 8"

# EAGI_AUDIO_FORMAT is an asterisk variable that specifies the sample rate and
# sample size (usually 16 bits per sample) of the caller's voice stream.
# Depending on the codec used here, you can get sample rate values ranging from
# 8000Hz (e.g. G.711 uLaw) to 48000Hz (e.g. opus).
echo "GET VARIABLE EAGI_AUDIO_FORMAT"
read line
EAGI_AUDIO_FORMAT=$(echo $line | sed -r 's/.*\((.*)\).*/\1/')

# 5 seconds of audio input are gathered in ( SAMPLE_RATE / sample_size ) * 5 bytes
# - SAMPLE_RATE is set as per EAGI_AUDIO_FORMAT
# - sample_size is set to 2 (16 bits per sample)
#
# We don't do much here to adapt the sample rate, this code should be improved
case "${EAGI_AUDIO_FORMAT}" in
"slin48")
  SAMPLE_RATE=48000
  ;;
*)
  SAMPLE_RATE=8000
  ;;
esac

# Temporary file to store raw audio samples
AUDIO_FILE=/tmp/audio-${SAMPLE_SIZE_BITS}_bits-${SAMPLE_RATE}_hz-${DURATION}_sec.raw

# We use `dd` here to copy the raw audio samples we're getting from file
# descriptor 3 (this is the Enhanced version in EAGI) to the temporary file.
# The number of blocks to copy is a function of the DURATION to record audio and
# the sample rate. SAMPLE_SIZE_BYTES cannot be changed as it is assumed that each
# sample is 16 bits in size.
let "COUNT = SAMPLE_RATE * SAMPLE_SIZE_BYTES * DURATION"
# By default, dd stores blocks of 512 bytes
let "BLOCKS = COUNT / 512"
echo "exec noop \"Number of bytes to store : ${COUNT}\""
read line

echo "exec noop \"Number of dd blocks to store : ${BLOCKS}\""
read line

echo "exec playback \"beep\""
read line

dd if=/dev/fd/3 count=${BLOCKS} of=${AUDIO_FILE}
echo "exec noop \"File saved !\""

echo "exec noop \"AUDIO_FILE : ${AUDIO_FILE}\""
read line
echo "exec noop \"SAMPLE_RATE : ${SAMPLE_RATE}\""
read line
echo "exec noop \"LANG : ${LANG}\""
read line

# Submit audio to Google Cloud Speech API and get the result
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/usr/local/node_programs/service_account_file.json
RES=$(${NODECMD} /usr/local/node_programs/nodejs-speech/samples/recognize.js sync ${AUDIO_FILE} -e LINEAR16 -r ${SAMPLE_RATE} -l ${LANG})

# clean up result returned from recognize.js :
# - remove new lines
# - remove 'Transcription :' header
RES=$(echo $RES | tr -d '\n' | sed -e 's/Transcription: \(.*$\)/\1/')

# Set GOOGLE_TRANSCRIPTION_RESULT variable, remove temporary file
# and continue dialplan execution
echo "set variable GOOGLE_TRANSCRIPTION_RESULT \"${RES}\""
read line

/bin/rm -f ${AUDIO_FILE}

exit 0
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Most easy way do that - use asterisk EAGI interface and read sound from stdin/stream to google.

However at current moment google speech recognition api is NOT stable. Some days it just stop working, after that start working next day.

Comment: I have tried that but it didn't work. Can u share sample code?